# Problem with screen sharing in Skype on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, screen, skype, sharing

I have a problem with sharing my screen and seeing other people's screen in Skype 4.3.0.37 on Ubuntu 16.04, the button is grayed out for me and when other people try to share their screen just nothing happens, it used to work fine once except for group calls.

Is there a way to fix this?